# Install Linux on headless Dell PowerEdge T340

Tags: system-installation

We have a Dell PowerEdge T340 without Linux installed.  Is it possible to do the installation without a monitor or keyboard connected?  I've tried connecting from a Mac laptop with an ethernet cable directly to the iDRAC port, but was unable to bring up the web UI.  I have RHEL on a USB stick ready to install.

Comment: This answer over at askubuntu should cover you. https://askubuntu.com/a/13107

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but it doesn't address this scenario.  Dell has the iDRAC system that, apparently, must be used to install from external media.  I'm unable to connect to that.

Comment: I can't understand from the question if you know the IP of iDRAC, ie you ping it, but there's a problem to the webUI. Or you don't connect at all, you don't even have iDRAC's IP.

Comment: I plugged in an ethernet cable direct from my MacBook (via USB-C to ethernet adapter) to the iDRAC port, with the MacBook networking configured to be a DHCP server.  I was able to see the connection, but couldn't connect to any port on the T340 side.